# It's possible to use weblate without any VCS ?

Tags: git, version-control, weblate

We want to use weblate in a public server to allow access to external translators, but the git repository of the project  is stored in a private network and we don't want to publish this project in a public environnement, neither with the most stricts authetication methods.

We're aware of the limitations due to this decission.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to translate the project in private git repo, the private repo should be reached by the weblate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to use Weblate without VCS. However you can utilize git submodules to separate translations from the source code and let Weblate access only this submodule. This is pretty well covered in the [Weblate manual](https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-limit-weblates-access-to-translations-only-without-exposing-source-code-to-it).